# How do I login successfully with the code I have?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

How do I use this code to make the login work? When the login button is click, it didn't login at all. Not sure what is the error as it's not shown.

```
login() {
    var url = 'https://login.app/login';
    var postData = JSON.stringify({
      // saving it as Email and will be used at server.js
      Email: this.loginForm.value['email'],
      Password: this.loginForm.value['password'],
    });
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-AllowMethods': 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE'
      })
    };
    this.http.post(url, postData, httpOptions).subscribe((data) => {
      console.log('postData:', postData)
      if (data == false) {
       this.loginfail()
      } 
      else if (data == true) {
        this.loginsuccess()
        this.modalController.dismiss();
      }
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Your backend works well?

Comment: @yash should be

Comment: Can you verify that the html is calling the correct function? Also if youre using reactive forms try doing ```this.loginForm.get('email').value```

Comment: What is the error that you are getting? Json.stringify is not required here you can just pass the Object. The url : 'https://login.app/login' giving 404 for me

Comment: check your console for error.

Comment: @MarcusCantu its called to login() and i have async setEmail() {
    await Storage.set({
    key: 'email',
    value: this.loginForm.value['email']
    });
  }

Comment: https://skippyforvercel.vercel.app/login @RahulCv

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib I'm sorry but how do I check that?

Comment: Your Server is giving 405 Status code That means post method is not allowed , Kindly check with Server Team

Comment: @RahulCvr You mean that my server.js might be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Your App is calling below Api for login

```
https://skippyforvercel.vercel.app/login
```

Its POST method , I tested this Api in POST man getting a 405 status code, currently your server is not supporting  POST method Please raise issue to Server Team.

[image]

[image]